# Disable NEW options in document library

Tags: sharepoint, outlook

I need to disable new item creation (new document) and Connect to Outlook in a specific document library.

I would like to remove the button completely if possible, but will settle for disabling it by eliminating the "Create a new document" dropdown as well as the on-click function of the New button itself.

The code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166148/hide-new-actions-upload-settings-menus-in-sharepoint-lists-document-libra) does not perform these removals, no matter how I configure it using the "new document" or "new item" or "connect to outlook" menu item names in the function. All the others work fine but I cannot get these to go away.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Argh - you should at least mention in what application you want to do that and not let us guess via a link to some code.

Comment: @gf - this question is tagged as sharepoint and it's pretty obvious he is talking about Windows Sharepoint Services.

Comment: Yes - i tagged it as sharepoint after guessing that from the link.

Comment: And just from reading through the text it was absolutely non-obvious for me what it was about.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: You could just remove creating new item permissions on that list, by [breaking role  inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459352.aspx) for that list.

Option 2: Add event receiver on ItemAdding event and cancel item creation process by setting `SPItemEventProperties.Cancel = true;`. [Examples are on the web](http://www.alexbruett.net/?p=10).

In both ways you wont be able to add new items through nothing - no outlook, no GUI, no webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a custom doc lib that you have control over (ie the template)? If that is the case you could have a look at the example mentioned here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/syedi/archive/2008/07/19/customizing-the-list-toolbar-template-wss-3-0-moss.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Remove the contribute permissions on the doc lib for the users?

That way they can't add/upload new documents anymore to the doc lib.